# ASP.net MVC javascript in partial view is not running

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Maybe someone that can help me to understand what is the problem or error with this call to a partial view that has its own javascript code.

**This is the main cshtml:**

```
@model  Ads_Negocio.FormTest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reportone";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div> <p>Parent view</p> </div>
<p>----------Partial view section-----------</p>
<div>
    <p>Partial view</p>
    @Html.Partial("Componente/_aTestView")
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("parent view renderign")
        });
    </script>
}
```

**the partial view _aTestView.cshtml:**

```
<button type="button" id="btnGraficNew">Run</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("partial view rendering");
        $("#btnGraficNew").click("click", function () {
            alert("Call from partial view");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Problems:

1. After view is rendereng alert inside partial view is never call.
2. When I press botton, it does not alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial View is loaded together with the parent view. Therefore, the javascript command should be reside on the parent view rather than the partial view itself.

Answer (score 3):

When you run your code you can see the below error in console window.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**Solution** - You should put the jquery reference in the head section of the _Layout.cshtml page. Once you do that your code will run as expected.
If you are using default bundle then below code will work.

```
<head>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.addEventListener works on partial views.

Put your code inside addeventlistener method.

For example this code works in my partial views only with addEventListener.

```
<script defer>
 window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#ddlBirim", function () {
        window.location.href = "/@controller/@action/" + $(this).val();
    });
 });
</script>
```